# Fetch - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I'm using Fetch to hit an API and map a JSON object. When I enter the url manually into a browser, the browser displays a json object. But when I use Fetch to get that same URL, (with my local build, i.e. `http://localhost:8000`) I get an error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

In console > network the Request URL is http://localhost:8000/undefined instead of the api url that I am using with Fetch.

Why is it not going to the api url?

Here's the Fetch block.

```
fetch({
    url: url,
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.map(event => renderEvent(event, data))).then((eventsMarkup) => {
    if (eventsNode) {
      eventsNode.innerHTML = eventsMarkup.join('');
    }
  });
```

Thoughts?

Comment: show us the format of the json response

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not using correct fetch syntax.
Try this

```
 fetch(url,
    {
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.map(event => renderEvent(event, data))).then((eventsMarkup) => {
        if (eventsNode) {
            eventsNode.innerHTML = eventsMarkup.join('');
        }
    });
```